# How to recover privileges with GetTokenInformation () ? c++

Tags: c++, winapi, window, access-token

I would like to recover all privileges from a username. For example privileges : "SE_ASSIGN_PRIMARY_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE", "SE_AUDIT_PRIVILEGE", "SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE"... I searched on the microsoft documentation and I found GetTokenInformation()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation but I do not understand how to access all the privileges and see the value of this privilege. 
Would anyone already use this method with an example or how to proceed please?

Comment: what you mean under *recover all privileges* ? enumerate all privileges with name, attributes or what ? *from a username* - from concrete process (say current) session, etc ?

Comment: I want to list all the privileges with the name and whether they are enabled or disabled....

Comment: so in what is your problem?  get token, query *TokenPrivileges*, you got array of *LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges*. walk by array (*PrivilegeCount* element in it). for convert luid to redable name - *LsaLookupPrivilegeName*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

BOOL CheckWindowsPrivilege(const TCHAR *Privilege)
{
    /* Checks for Privilege and returns True or False. */
    LUID luid;
    PRIVILEGE_SET privs;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    HANDLE hToken;
    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) return FALSE;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, Privilege, &luid)) return FALSE;
    privs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    privs.Control = PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY;
    privs.Privilege[0].Luid = luid;
    privs.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    BOOL bResult;
    PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &privs, &bResult);
    return bResult;
}

int wmain(void)
{
    if (!CheckWindowsPrivilege(SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME))
    {
        wprintf(L"I do not have SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    wprintf(L"I do have SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And then call the [`SetPrivilege`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--)(not the win32 api but the function from the MSDN example)

Comment: thank you for your example so if I want to know the privileges in relation to a domain name , I replace the method GetProcess () with the domain name?  And I repeat the code for all the privileges?

Comment: The function LookupPrivilegeValue return always false with  error NO SUCH PRIVILEGE , do you know where it can come from?

Comment: which privilege did you pass in?

Comment: I solved the mistake because I was passing SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME and doing SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege it works.... and if I want to know the privileges in relation to a domain name , I replace the method GetProcess () with the domain name? And I repeat the code for all the privileges?

Comment: When a user logs on, the system produces an access token that contains a list of the user's privileges. The example is for the current user. And if you want to get another domain user's privileges, you need to use [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) to get the token handle.(But this cannot log on to a remote computer)

Comment: Ok but for the function LogonUserA(lpzUsername, lpszDomain,lpszPassword,dwLogonType,dwLogonProvider,phToken), UserName is my name Domain is domain name but what password should I put?

Comment: "*A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the plaintext password for the user account specified by lpszUsername.*" The logon password of the username.

Comment: Well, did you mean which `dwLogonType` to select? It depends, read the document and select one.

Comment: I use a current user, my problem is solved, Thank you for your answers and your help